# Resource Bundle in JSTL shows question marks?

Tags: jsp, maven, jstl, resourcebundle

In my login.jsp i have the following:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:setLocale value="${sessionScope.locale}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.ubbcluj.project.res.myProp" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And try to display the username in the following manner:

myProp.properties files looks like this and is located in "/Project/src/main/java/com/ubbcluj/project/res":

```
username = Username
pass = Password
register = Register
login = Login
```

When the page loads it appears in the following way:
???username???

I have tried adding a variable as shown in other tutorials like :

```
<fmt:message key="username" var="${lang}" />
```

But still didnt work.

I can share my whole project , i know its not perfect ,but it's only a study project any suggestions are welcome.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/biavimrexisfskp/o9q57IoiUl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're building your project with Maven, and Maven expects non-Java files to be in `src/main/resources`, and not in `src/main/java` (which should only contain .java files). So your properties file is not copied to the target directory and included into the deployed application.

Comment: so if i move my files to src/main/resources how should i write the setbundle basename? I tried <fmt:setBundle basename="resources.myProp" /> but still the same

Comment: I wrote it like <fmt:setBundle basename="myProp" /> and it works, thank you

Comment: You should keep the same package/folder hierarchy as the one you had in the src/main/java folder, and use the exaxct same base name for the bundle.